# Taylor series (or equivalent at $\epsilon\to0$) of the integral over $x$ of a function of $x$ and $\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, power-series, taylor-expansion

I have a function $f$ of two arguments, defined as
$$
f(x,\epsilon)=\epsilon\left( e^{-\frac{(x-\epsilon)^2}{2}} - e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\right) + \frac{1-\epsilon}{\sqrt{1+\epsilon}}\left( e^{-\frac{x^2}{2(1+\epsilon)}} - e^{-\frac{(x-\epsilon^2)^2}{2(1+\epsilon)}}\right)
$$
for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon\in(0,1)$; and I would like to get an equivalent (or even, ideally, a Taylor series expansion with 2 terms or more) of the quantity
$$\Delta(\epsilon) \stackrel{\rm{}def}{=}\int_\mathbb{R}|f(x,\epsilon)| dx$$
for $\epsilon\to 0^+$.

Doing a series expansion wrt $\epsilon$ of $|f(x,\epsilon)|$ hints that it should be of the form $\kappa \epsilon^3 + o(\epsilon^3)$, "as" $|f(x,\epsilon)|=\kappa(x)\epsilon^3 + O_x(\epsilon^4)$ (where the constants in the big-Oh notation depend on $x$, and $x\mapsto \kappa(x)\in L_1$)... but the expansion I get has not an explicit form, and then I fall short of arguments when it comes to integrating the "$O_x(\epsilon^4)$" on $\mathbb R$ wrt $x$. I did try for an expression as power series (wrt $\epsilon$) and using the related theorems to swap integration and summation, but again the coefficients $(P_k(x))_k$ of the said power series are functions of $x$ and might -- for all I know -- behave very badly once integrated wrt $x$.

(A numerical plot and curve fitting also suggests that $\kappa \epsilon^3 + o(\epsilon^3)$ is likely to be the right solution.)

Any help would be appreciated... Thanks!

- E.g, with Mathematica:

`Series[eps*( -(1/(E^(x^2/2) Sqrt[2 Pi])) + 1/(E^((x - eps)^2/2) Sqrt[2 Pi]) ) + (1-eps)*( 1/(E^(x^2/(2 (1 + eps))) Sqrt[2 Pi] Sqrt[1 + eps]) - 1/(E^((x - eps^2)^2/(2 (1 + eps))) Sqrt[2 Pi] Sqrt[1 + eps]) ), {eps,0,3}];`

**Edit** there was a typo in the formula (not the code): the third gaussian had a $(1+\epsilon)^2$ instead of $(1+\epsilon)$ in the denominator of the argument.
Essentially, the first two gaussian functions are pdfs with variance $1$, the last 2 with variances $\sqrt{1+\epsilon}$.

Comment: your Mathematica code have $\pi$ in the formula of $f$ while your original $f$ doesn't

Comment: @Norbert: yes, it is the same function up to an extra coefficient $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ — it is in the orginal problem I'm trying to solve, but I removed it from the question as it is irrelevant and does not change anything to the answer (up to multiplication by that constant).

Comment: The difficulty stems from the absolute value; otherwise the problem would be routine. Plot the function $g(x,\epsilon):=e^{x^2/2} f(x,\epsilon)$ and look at the sign of $g$ when $\epsilon$ is small. Expanding $g$ into powers of $\epsilon$ gives polynomials in $x$ as coefficients, and integrating these against $e^{-x^2/2}$ is no problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This uses the same basic idea as Christian Blatter's answer.  Observe that
$$
f(x,\epsilon) \;=\; g_3(x)\epsilon^3 \,+\, g_4(x)\epsilon^4 \,+\, g_5(x)\epsilon^5 \,+\, \cdots
$$
where each $g_n(x)$ is the product of a polynomial with $e^{-x^2/2}$:
$$
\begin{align*}
g_3(x) \;&=\; \frac12 \bigl(-x^3 + x^2 + 5x -1\bigr)e^{-x^2/2} \\[6pt]
g_4(x) \;&=\; \frac{1}{24} \bigl(-3x^5+46x^3-12x^2-93x+12)e^{-x^2/2} \\[6pt]
g_5(x) \;&=\; \frac{1}{48}\bigl(-x^7 + 27 x^5 - 10 x^4 - 165 x^3 + 84 x^2 + 195 x - 54\bigr)e^{-x^2/2} \\[6pt]   
g_6(x) \;&=\; \left(\tfrac{- 5 x^9 + 220 x^7 - 
 120 x^6 - 2714 x^5 + 2280 x^4 + 10020 x^3 - 8280 x^2  - 7725 x  + 3240}{1920}\right)e^{-x^2/2}\\
&\;\vdots
\end{align*}
$$
The function $f(x,\epsilon)$ is zero along three curves:
[image]
These curves hit the $x$-axis at the three roots of the polynomial $x^3 - x^2 - 5x + 1$.  It is easy to check that $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon}[f(x,\epsilon)/\epsilon^3]\ne 0$ at these three points, so the picture really does look like this in some neighborhood of the $x$-axis, and the intersections really are transverse.

If we write the three curves as equations of the form
$$
x \;=\; \psi_1(\epsilon),\qquad x=\psi_2(\epsilon),\qquad x=\psi_3(\epsilon)
$$
Note that the functions $\psi_1$, $\psi_2$, and $\psi_3$ are $C^\infty$, by the Implicit Function Theorem.  Then 
$$
\Delta(\epsilon) \;=\; \int_{-\infty}^{\psi_1(\epsilon)} \!\!f(x,\epsilon)\,dx \,-\, \int_{\psi_1(\epsilon)}^{\psi_2(\epsilon)} \!\!f(x,\epsilon)\,dx \,+\, \int_{\psi_2(\epsilon)}^{\psi_3(\epsilon)} \!\!f(x,\epsilon)\,dx \,-\, \int_{\psi_3(\epsilon)}^{\infty} \!\!f(x,\epsilon)\,dx
$$
We can use this to derive the first few terms of a Taylor expansion for $\Delta(\epsilon)$.

Specifically, we have
$$
\Delta(\epsilon) \;=\; \kappa \epsilon^3 \,+\, \lambda \epsilon^4 \,+\,\mu\epsilon^5 \,+\, o(\epsilon^5)
$$
for some constants $\kappa$, $\lambda$, $\mu$.  There is a nice formula for $\kappa$:
$$
\begin{align*}
\kappa \;&=\; \int_{-\infty}^\infty |g_3(x)|\,dx \\[6pt]
&=\; e^{-\alpha^2/2}(\alpha^2-\alpha-3)\,-\,e^{-\beta^2/2}(\beta^2-\beta-3)\,+\,e^{-\gamma^2/2}(\gamma^2-\gamma-3) \\[6pt]
&\approx\; 3.5519079
\end{align*}
$$
where $\alpha<\beta<\gamma$ are the three roots of the polynomial $x^3 - x^2 - 5x + 1$.

The formula for $\lambda$ is similarly nice:
$$
\begin{align*}
\lambda \;&=\; \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{g_3(x) g_4(x)}{|g_3(x)|}dx \\[6pt]
&=\; e^{-\alpha^2/2}p(\alpha)\,-\,e^{-\beta^2/2}p(\beta)\,+\,e^{-\gamma^2/2}p(\gamma) \\[6pt]
&\approx\; -3.307248
\end{align*}
$$
where $p(x) = \dfrac{1}{12}\bigl(3x^4-34x^2+12x+25\bigr)$.

Things get a little bit dicey after that, since the values of $\psi_1'(0)$, $\psi_2'(0)$, and $\psi_3'(0)$ come into play.  In particular,
$$
\begin{align*}
\mu \;&=\; \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{g_3(x) g_5(x)}{|g_3(x)|}dx \,+\, \bigl(2g_4(\alpha)+g_3'(\alpha)\bigr)\psi_1'(0) \\[6pt]
&\qquad 
-\, \bigl(2g_4(\beta)+g_3'(\beta)\bigr)\psi_2'(0)
+\, \bigl(2g_4(\gamma)+g_3'(\gamma)\bigr)\psi_3'(0)
\end{align*}
$$
It's possible to compute the values of $\psi_1'(0)$, $\psi_2'(0)$, and $\psi_3'(0)$ by examining the gradient of $f(x,\epsilon)/\epsilon^3$ near the points $(\alpha,0)$, $(\beta,0)$, and $\gamma(0)$.  The result is that
$$
\psi_1'(0) = q(\alpha),\qquad \psi_2'(0)=q(\beta),\qquad \psi_3'(0)=q(\gamma)
$$
where
$$
q(x) \;=\; \frac{3x^5-46x^3+12x^2+93x-12}{12(x^4-x^3-8x^2+3x+5)}.
$$
In particular,
$$
\psi_1'(0)\approx -0.832825,\qquad \psi_2'(0) \approx 0.0971987,\qquad \psi_3'(0)\approx 1.06896.$$
Using these formulas, I'm getting that $\mu\approx 3.70537$, but this is complicated enough that I'm not very confident about this value.

**Edit:** In the comments, Clement asks how we know that the remainder term in the expansion
$$
\Delta(\epsilon) \;=\; \kappa \epsilon^3 \,+\, \lambda \epsilon^4 \,+\,\mu\epsilon^5 \,+\, o(\epsilon^5)
$$
is indeed $o(\epsilon^5)$.  Well, observe that the function $f(x,\epsilon)$ has a simple antiderivative with respect to $x$:
$$
\begin{align*}
F(x,\epsilon) \;&=\; \epsilon\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{x-\epsilon}{\sqrt2}\right)-\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt2}\right)\right) \\
 &\qquad+\, (1-\epsilon)\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2(1+\epsilon)}}\right)-\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{x-\epsilon^2}{\sqrt{2(1+\epsilon)}}\right)\right)
\end{align*}
$$
where $\mathrm{erf}$ is the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).  Since $\mathrm{erf}$ is an entire function, it is clear that $F(x,\epsilon)$ is analytic on $\mathbb{R}\times(-1,1)$.  It is easy to check that $F(x,\epsilon)\to 0$ as $x\to\pm\infty$, so
$$
\Delta(\epsilon) \;=\; 2 F(\psi_1(\epsilon),\epsilon)-2F(\psi_2(\epsilon),\epsilon)+2F(\psi_3(\epsilon),\epsilon)
$$
Since $\psi_1$, $\psi_2$, and $\psi_3$ are $C^\infty$, we can compute the power series for $\Delta(\epsilon)$ in the usual way, giving the results above.  The remainder is $o(\epsilon^5)$ because of Taylor's Theorem.

Comment: Thanks — it looks like the solution I was looking for!

Comment: Actually, just a last question: I understand how you get the constants $\mu,\kappa,\lambda$, but how do you argue that the remaining part of what you integrat is indeed $o(\epsilon^5)$ — is that trivial?

Comment: @ClementC. I added an explanation to the end of my post.

Answer (score 3):

(**Edited.** I had the wrong sign between the two main parts of $f$.)

The idea is: Get a global overview and then develop anything in sight into a power series with respect to $t$ (which is your $\epsilon$).

Begin by replacing $f$ with the function
$$g(x,t):=e^{x^2/2} f(x,t)\ .$$
Then $g$ can be written in the neighborhood of $(0,0)$ in the form
$$g(x,t)={1\over2}(-1+5x+x^2-x^3) t^3 +{1\over24}(12 -93 x+\ldots) t^4+\ldots\ .$$
The polynomial $-1+5x+x^2-x^3$ has three real zeros $x_1\doteq-1.9$, $x_2\doteq0.195$, $x_3\doteq2.7$. These will be the constant terms in three functions $t\mapsto x=\psi_i(t)$ that describe where $x\mapsto f(x,t)$ changes sign for fixed small $t$.

Comment: I do not think this is correct.  The function $g(x,t)$ seems to be zero along three separate curves.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: How do you get your first expansion (for $g$)? Mathematica gives me something of the form:
$$
\frac{(-1 + 5 x + x^2  - x^3 )}{2}t^3 + O(t^4)
$$
using Series[] to get the Taylor expansion.